# I need the balance of my hard disk drive

Tags: upgrade, disk, drive

I want to update from 16.04 to ubuntu to 18.04.4 so I want to know the balance of my hard disk drive before I update

Comment: What do you mean by balance? If you mean, the space available, the df command should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Bruni,  I'll try the df command.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the amount of remaining space on your hard drive then in the terminal type:

`df -h --total`

see [How Do I Find the Amount of Free Space on My Hard Drive with Command Line?](https://ahmadawais.com/ubuntu-find-amount-free-space-hard-drive-command-line/) for more.